# Why does MediaView of Facebook Ads repeat image 3 times?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-audience-network

I'm facing this problem when I try to add **Facebook Audience Network** to my Android app. I implement **Facebook Ads** as described in this tutorial:
[Facebook Native Ads in Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android/native-api)

The problem is: the cover image repeats 3 times (like this image):
[image]

I use a custom layout `xml` for displaying Ads. Here is a part of the `xml` file:

```
<com.facebook.ads.MediaView
    android:id="@+id/native_ad_media"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:contentDescription=""
    />
```

And here is the Java code:

```
    MediaView nativeAdMedia = (MediaView)adView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_media);

nativeAdMedia.setNativeAd(nativeAd);
```

Any one can show me where I am wrong?

Comment: Please give me the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `layout_height` explicitly. The MediaView object can have multiple different creative types (eg video, carousel), so will expand to use the space by creating blurred and mirrored wrapper images.

Comment: Do you have any idea what Aspect Ratio that would make that blur-issue disappear ?